# How to make a 2-column layout of images in a div?

Tags: css, xslt

I have a list of thumbnails that I would like to layout properly depending on the amount of thumbnails. All the thumbnails are coded like this:

```
<a href="..."><img /></a>
```

I would like a 2-column setup with 4 thumbnails in each column - all managed by css.

```
<div id="bx-pager">
    <a href="..."><img /></a>
    <a href="..."><img /></a>
    <a href="..."><img /></a>
    <a href="..."><img /></a>
    <!-- here should column 2 -->
    <a href="..."><img /></a>
    <a href="..."><img /></a>
    <a href="..."><img /></a>
</div>
```

Is this possible using some css rules?

Nb. I am using some XSLT to generate a list of the thumbnails in Umbraco using this script. The script can be modified, but XSLT is not my strong point - so hoping for some advice on either css or xslt.

```
Gallery.xslt:

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE xsl:stylesheet [ <!ENTITY nbsp "&#x00A0;"> ]>
<xsl:stylesheet 
    version="1.0" 
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" 
    xmlns:msxml="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt"
    xmlns:umbraco.library="urn:umbraco.library" xmlns:Exslt.ExsltCommon="urn:Exslt.ExsltCommon" xmlns:Exslt.ExsltDatesAndTimes="urn:Exslt.ExsltDatesAndTimes" xmlns:Exslt.ExsltMath="urn:Exslt.ExsltMath" xmlns:Exslt.ExsltRegularExpressions="urn:Exslt.ExsltRegularExpressions" xmlns:Exslt.ExsltStrings="urn:Exslt.ExsltStrings" xmlns:Exslt.ExsltSets="urn:Exslt.ExsltSets" 
    exclude-result-prefixes="msxml umbraco.library Exslt.ExsltCommon Exslt.ExsltDatesAndTimes Exslt.ExsltMath Exslt.ExsltRegularExpressions Exslt.ExsltStrings Exslt.ExsltSets ">


<xsl:output method="xml" omit-xml-declaration="yes"/>

<xsl:param name="currentPage"/>

 <xsl:variable name="mediaFolderId" select="number($currentPage/mediaFolderId)" />
    <xsl:variable name="thumbWidth" select="number(58)" />
    <xsl:variable name="thumbHeight" select="number(58)" />
    <xsl:variable name="imageW" select="number(300)" />
    <xsl:variable name="imageH" select="number(300)" /> 
        <xsl:variable name="i" select="number(-1)" />

    <xsl:template match="/">

        <!-- Displays all images from a folder in the Media Library -->

        <xsl:if test="number($mediaFolderId)">

        <ul class="bxslider">           
            <xsl:for-each select="umbraco.library:GetMedia($mediaFolderId, true())/Image">
                <xsl:if test="umbracoFile !=''">
                    <li><a href="{umbracoFile}" title="{@nodeName}" class="gal"><img src="/imageGen.ashx?image={umbraco.library:UrlEncode(umbracoFile)}&amp;width={$imageW}&amp;height={$imageH}" width="{$imageW}" height="{$imageH}" alt="{@nodeName}" title="{@nodeName}" /></a></li>
                </xsl:if>
            </xsl:for-each>
        </ul>
        <div id="bx-pager">         
            <xsl:for-each select="umbraco.library:GetMedia($mediaFolderId, true())/Image">
                <xsl:if test="umbracoFile !=''">
                    <xsl:call-template name="section" />            
                </xsl:if>
            </xsl:for-each>         
        </div>
        </xsl:if>

</xsl:template>
        <xsl:template name="section">           
            <a href="javascript:void(0);" data-slide-index="{0 + count(preceding-sibling::Image)}"><img src="/imageGen.ashx?image={umbraco.library:UrlEncode(umbracoFile)}&amp;width={$thumbWidth}&amp;height={$thumbHeight}&amp;=t" width="{$thumbWidth}" height="{$thumbHeight}" alt="{@nodeName}" title="{@nodeName}" /></a>             
        </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: you can use `column` CSS rules see: http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-multicol/#columns

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If column doesn't feet your need , you may simply use float and display:

[DEMO](http://codepen.io/gc-nomade/pen/gwlmH/)

for single images :

```
img:nth-child(odd) {/* you can include a loop in your xlst to apply a class instead */
  float:left;
  clear:left;
  margin-bottom:0.2em;
}
img {
  display:block;
    margin:0 0.2em 0.2em 0;
}
```

For links, it is basicly the same, **you need to size them** or display them as `display:table;` instead `block;`

Comment: Thanks a lot - just what I was looking for :) I will just do something like 
.bx-pager img:nth-child(odd) to avoid modifying the xslt.